# My message quota is full; how do I delete messages?

Tags: thunderbird

I'm not receiving incoming messages and have the following message in Folder Properties:

> Quota Root:  "ROOT"
>   Usage:  321740 of 10236kB used
>   Status:  3143% full.

How do I empty this?

Comment: Just select msgs and delete?

Comment: Tried that already thanks. It deletes the local copies, but it hasn't deleted the originals on the remote server, which is full.

Comment: Are you using a mail client set to POP3? Those usually have a 'leave a copy on server' option. And the server is the place which is full.

Comment: Hi, no its on Imap, just changing it over to POP now.  Thanks

Comment: If it is on IMAP, then local copies will be deleted from the server as well

Answer (score 1):

Go to your service provider and delete all the emails from inbox and spam. You can also export your mails if you want.